# Access - how to calculate with items in different rows

Tags: ms-access

I know it is possible to use access to calculate items in the same row. But 
Is it possible to calculate items in different rows?

For example, I want to multiply "speedkmhr" with the next row's direction.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncPIW.png

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it using VBA function. Press CTRL+G in Access, then click menu Insert > Module. Copy & Paste the following into that module:

```
Function fGetNextDirection(lngID As Long)
  Dim rst AS DAO.Recordset
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 2 FROM TAXIDATA WHERE " & _ 
    "PosID = lngID & " ORDER BY PosID")
  rst.MoveLast
  If rst.RecordCount = 2 Then
    fGetNextDirection = rst!Direction
  Else
    fGetNextDirection = 0
  End If
  rst.Close
  Set rst = Nothing
End Function
```

Then, in query add new field:

Product: NZ(SpeedKmHr) * fGetNextDirection(PosID)

In case this is last record, result will be 0.